# Modificacion estructura del codigo excel

Tags: excel, vba, optimización

Esta estructura ¿se puede acortar de alguna manera?

```
 If j = 5 Then
    lista = lista1
 ElseIf j = 6 Then
    lista = lista1
 ElseIf j = 7 Then
    lista = lista2
 ElseIf j = 8 Then
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qué debería hacer j=8? Está cortado

Hay varias formas de abordar esto, con un CASE tienes varias formas de tratarlo ya que te permitirá tratar intervalos, grupos, casos individuales...

```vb
Select Case j 
Case 5, 6
    lista = lista1 
Case 7
    lista = lista2
Case Else    ' Case opcional de escape
    Debug.Print "Ninguno de los anteriores casos se ha validad" 
End Select
```

Tienes toda la info en [MS DOCS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement)

Answer (score 1):

A lo mejor esto te funcione.

```
if(j>4 and j<9) then
lista=lista1
```

Comment: Cuando es 7, se asigna lista2. Este código es incorrecto

Answer (score 0):

Esto podria servir con bloque IF

```
If j>=5 And j<7 Then
 lista = lista1
ElseIf j=7 Then
 lista = lista2
EndIf
```